# Ajax - how to display json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to display the json data correctly. I've got all the data running but I can't displaying them correctly.

How can I append the names, images and urls so they display like this:

```
<div>name</div>
<img src="url from jason goes here">
<a href="url">url of page</a>
```

```js
$(function(){
 $.ajax({
  url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars",
  method: "GET",
  success: function(data) {
   //console.log(data);
   //$(".git-user").html(JSON.stringify(data));

   $.each(data.items, function(i, items) {
    $("#name").append(items.name);
    $("#image").append(items.owner.avatar_url);
    $("#repo").append(items.html_url);
   });
  },
  error: function() {
   console.log(data);
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="git-user">
 <div id="name"></div>
 <div id="image"></div> 
 <a href="#" id="repo"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: How is the data being incorrectly displayed? if you do `console.log(data)` in success function, what is the result? How is your JSON structure?

Comment: @pablito.aven all the datas are correctly called. I need to display them with correct html.

Comment: couple of things, don't use ID within each function, for div you need text, for image you need to add attr ("src",url) and for "a" tag you need .attr("href",url)

Comment: @KarthikGanesan thanks yes makes sense, could you put it together please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to generate one container for every item being loaded. Below is a sample code on how to do it, I hope this leads you in the right direction.

```
        $.each(data.items, function(i, items) {
            var html_to_append = '<div class="git-user"><div class="name">'+items.name+'</div><div class="image">'+items.owner.avatar_url+'</div><a class="repo">'+items.html_url+'</a></div>';
           $('#items-container').append(html_to_append);
        });
```

For this solution, you should also have to change the `id`s to have them as classes, since you will probably have more than just one of each.

This will be the template to display items:

```
<div class="git-user">
  <div class="name"></div>
  <div class="image"></div> 
  <a href="#" class="repo"></a>
 </div>
```

This will be how your html looks like(it will be filled with the above):

```
<div id="items-container"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you put it in to a snippet please? I can make it to work

Comment: I normally would but I don't have the time right now. Anyways I bet you can manage to do it with the starting point I gave you. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `prepend` to append the Elements dynamically.

Please note that i have removed the dynamic element in `div`. So, that elements can be added dynamically. You can format the code below as per your need.

```
<div id="git-user">

</div
```

```js
$(function(){
 $.ajax({
  url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars",
  method: "GET",
  success: function(data) {
   //console.log(data);
   //$(".git-user").html(JSON.stringify(data));

   $.each(data.items, function(i, items) {
    
        $('#git-user').prepend('<span>' + items.name+ '</span>');
        $('#git-user').prepend('<img src="' + items.owner.avatar_url + '"/>');
        $('#git-user').prepend('<img src="' + items.html_url + '"/>');
   });
  },
  error: function() {
   console.log(data);
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="git-user">
 
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know why they display 2 images?

Comment: One is `avatar_url` and other is `html_url`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Lets have a container that will display all the results -->
<div id="results">

</div>

var $container = $('#results'),
    html = '';

$.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
    // build the html
    html += '<div>' +
              '<div class="name">' + item.name + '</div>' + 
              '<div class="image"><img src="' + item.owner.avatar_url + '"></div>' + 
              '<a href="' + item.html_url + '"></a>' + 
           '</div>';
});

// append it to the container
$container.append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(function(){
 $.ajax({
  url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars",
  method: "GET",
  success: function(data) {
   //console.log(data);
   //$(".git-user").html(JSON.stringify(data));
            var $wrapper = $('#git-user');
            var $nameElement = $('#name');
            var $imageElement = $('#image');
            var $repoElement = $('#repo');
            
   $.each(data.items, function(i, items) {
        var $clonedName = $nameElement.clone().html(items.name);
        var $clonedImage = $imageElement.clone().attr('src',items.owner.avatar_url);
       var $clonedRepo = $repoElement.clone().html(items.html_url);
    $wrapper.append($clonedName);
        $wrapper.append($clonedImage );
        $wrapper.append($clonedRepo );
   });
  },
  error: function() {
   console.log(data);
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="git-user">
 <div id="name"></div>
 <img id="image" width="42" height="42" style="display:block;margin:10px"> 
 <a href="#" id="repo"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to see the image actually

Comment: well you will need to use an `img` element and not a `div`. i'll update the answer

Comment: @user3699998 check the snippet again

Answer (score -1):

Use `text` instead of `append`

```js
$(function(){
 $.ajax({
  url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars",
  method: "GET",
  success: function(data) {
   //console.log(data);
   //$(".git-user").html(JSON.stringify(data));

   $.each(data.items, function(i, items) {
    $("#name").text(items.name);
    $("#image").text(items.owner.avatar_url);
    $("#repo").text(items.html_url);
   });
  },
  error: function() {
   console.log(data);
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="git-user">
 <div id="name"></div>
 <div id="image"></div> 
 <a href="#" id="repo"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is **not** correct. It will just replace the text for each item.

Comment: Thanks but I need to display all of them in a nice orther

Comment: @user3699998 I see, then you need to clone the elements and append data to them in the loop and finally append the result to the `"#git-user` element.